# Docker Rocket chat Rest api upload file error 413 Entity too large

Tags: file-upload, rocket.chat

I am using rocket chat rest API, every thing works good, but when i upload file to rocket chat rest api, it shows error `413 Request Entity Too Large`, but when i upload file from website it uploaded any size of fie.

After checking all scenario, I concluded that file size less than and equal to 1 mb is uploaded successfully, and greater than 1 MB shows this error `413 Request Entity Too Large`.

I upload file from post man using this url
https://rocket.chat.url/api/v1/rooms.upload/RoomId

**Headers:**

> Content-Type:application/x-www-form-urlencoded
>
> X-Auth-Token:User-Token
>
> X-User-Id:User-Id

**Form-Data:**

> file - selected file

**Html result Error**

```
<html>
<head><title>413 Request Entity Too Large</title></head>
<body bgcolor="white">
<center><h1>413 Request Entity Too Large</h1></center>
<hr><center>nginx/1.10.3 (Ubuntu)</center>
</body>
</html>
```

when File successfully insert it shows following.

```
{
   "success": true
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

After checking many scenarios and search many urls i get solution from [this](https://github.com/RocketChat/Rocket.Chat.Android/issues/1050#issuecomment-384117403).

I have used [rocket chat docker](https://rocket.chat/docs/installation/docker-containers/) and I append one line to [nginx](https://nginx.org/en/) config file.

**Solution:**

1. login to ubuntu server
2. write `sudo nano /etc/nginx/nginx.conf` and hit enter
3. Add or update `client_max_body_size` in

> ```
> http {
>
>     client_max_body_size 8M; #used your exceeded limit instead of 8M
>
>     #other lines...
>
> }
> ```

4. Restart [nginx](https://nginx.org/en/) by command `service nginx restart` or `systemctl restart nginx`
5. Uploading larger file again, and it is successful.

Comment: Thanks! This works smooth. Please note though that // are not recognized as comments, use # instead, otherwise restarting nginx failes.

Comment: @IvicaPesovski Got it, and update answer also